# Count down daily email sent out

Tags: outlook, basic

```vba
Dim targetDate As Date

Sub ScheduleEmail()
    ' Set the target date
    targetDate = DateValue("2024-01-14")
    ' Schedule the SendCountdownEmail macro to run at 9 AM every day
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:53:00"), "SendCountdownEmail"
End Sub

Sub SendCountdownEmail()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim daysLeft As Integer
    
    ' Calculate the number of days left until the target date
    daysLeft = targetDate - Date

    ' Create a new Outlook mail item
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMail = olApp.CreateItem(0)

    With olMail
        .To = "sam.wilson@toyota.com"  ' Replace with the recipient's email address
        .Subject = "Countdown to Special Day"
        .Body = "There are " & daysLeft & " days left until January 14, 2024."
        .Send
    End With

    ' Clean up
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

    ' Reschedule the SendCountdownEmail macro to run at 9 AM tomorrow
    Application.OnTime TimeValue("05:53:00"), "SendCountdownEmail"
End Sub
```

I get a run time error 6 Overflow
or Runtime error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method

I was expecting to send out an email daily at a specific time that gave the number of days left before a certain date

Comment: it would help if you add to your question, where you get the error(s) and what you do to trigger one or the other - or if you cannot predict, which error you will get.

Comment: And which lines throw the errors?